# HTML TABLE TO PDF BY DOMPDF

Tags: php, pdf, html-table, export, dompdf

I have a database table contains some information , and I'm retrieving the information of the table in an html table , i'm trying to export this table into pdf file , i'm getting ??? on some numbers for unknown reasons , I'm using Xampp  , PHP version 5.4 . DomPdf 0.6
i will share my code below:

```
     <?php
        $contentinvoice=
       '<html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
            <style> body { font-family: Helvetica; font-size:10px; } </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <table width="100%">
        <tr>
        <td>Code</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Price</td>
        </tr>';

        $select="SELECT * FROM invoicelines";
        $run=mysql_query($select,$con);
        if(!$run)die("Error".mysql_error());
        for($counter=1;$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($run);$counter++){

             $contentinvoice.=
               '<tr>
                    <td align="center">'.$row['code'].'</td>
                    <td align="center">'.$row['description'].'</td>
                    <td align="center">'.$row['quantity'].'</td>
                    <td align="center">'.$row['price'].'</td>
                </tr>';
        }

 $contentinvoice.='</table></body></html>';

 require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

 $dompdf = new Dompdf();
 $dompdf->load_html(ob_get_clean());
 $dompdf->load_html($contentinvoice, 'UTF-8');
 $dompdf->set_paper('A4');
 $dompdf->render();
 $dompdf->stream("dompdf_out.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));
```

?>

I'm getting result same what i need but some numbers are substituted with ???
Like

```
Code              Description              Quantity             Price
124?1231          Item 1                      ?                  ?.189
412?3123?         Item 2                      ?                  ?.234
```

**NOTE : 
If i change in the header the font face to DejaVu Sans the symbol ? will convert to Arabic Numbers like ?.189 will be *١.189***

Comment: First of all stop use mysql change to mysqli, second try to change load_html without UTF-8

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Yea it is only example using mysql , already tried load_html without utf-8, same result...

Comment: add mysql_set_charset('utf8', $mysql); to connection but remember to upgrade all to mysqli_

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Same ... Not Working

Comment: You add it on connection code true?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Yes I added it To the connection ...

Comment: `$mysql = mysql_connect(...); 
mysql_select_db('...', $mysql);  
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $mysql); ` - add `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: Also tried before also didn't work ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205916/discussion-between-simone-rossaini-and-moussa).

Answer (score 0):

**Display table or show table borders in HTML webpage to pdf export using dompdf/dompdf or barryvdh/laravel-dompdf in php**

All you need to do is to just add the below few lines of CSS to your code and all done.

```
table td, table th {
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

I hope this is helpful, thanks.